# Facebook pixel/Google Adwords conversion tracking setup when running multiple types of ad for the same landing page

Tags: google-ads, conversions, goal-tracking

Let's say I have a page `test.com/page` which I'm running ads for.

I'm using both Google Adwords and Facebook Ads. In order to track Adwords conversion, I need to call the below function every time user finished the last action.

```
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'XXXX',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
```

The problem is, the function gets called even if user came from Facebook Ads.

My question is:

- Does Google Adwords count that as 1 conversion?
- Is Google Adwords system smart enough to only count conversion if user coming from its ads
- What happens if visitors hack it and execute the function manually multiple times (by using Browser Console for example)

Same question to Facebook pixel setup.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure on this one, but Facebook ads are also probably an event conversion. So it makes sense that they're being combined into the same event tracker. You can add custom categories to events. Here is a code that I use on certain links that may help you: onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'insertcategoryname', 'Click', 'insertsubcategoryname');"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a conversion from Adwords is required an initial click, so, the answer to your question is that there will be no problem at all.

On Facebook, you can see all the conversions for all the traffic sources, although the only ones associated to a campaign will be the ones that come from a click on the ad.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. I will accept this answer.